# whether it is correct to call the application function from library function?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

we have one application which mainly consists of 3 major modules.

Now I am instructed to change the 3 modules of my application as 3 Dynamic libraries. Reason behind this activity is if any changes in one of the module will not affect the release cycle of the other modules.

Till now it holds good for me.

But the problem is some of the function in the application(Executable) is required by the library files.

So they were calling the function which is wrote in the application from library file.
I cannot digest this, because application can call the library, but how library can call the application.

Since this is our internal library, can we do this as other suggested me?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a `SetCallback` kind of function from the Library, taking a function pointer. You call this from executable, passing a function pointer available in executable. The library will record the address of this function and would call it later.

**EXE:**

```
void CallMe(int param);

...
SetCallback(Callme);
```

**Library**:

```
void(*func_in_exe)(int);

void SetCallback(void(*pf)(int))
{
    func_in_exe = pf;    
}

void SomeLibraryFunction()
{
if (func_in_exe != NULL)
   (*func_in_exe)(100);
}
```

Where `SetCallback` expects a function-pointer of type `void (*)(int)`. This function would update a global/static variable of the same type.

If you have latest C++ compiler, you can wrap it in `std::function` object, also simplify the function pointer syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You need a call back function.

Create a function in the library, that takes a function pointer as a parameter. The application should then call this library function and pass a pointer to a function that the library can store to be called later.